# Full width centered grid layout

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to achieve a layout with CSS grid for the following content

- Header
- Content
- Footer

I have an `AppContainer` component that is a grid with the following specifications

```
const AppContainer = styled.div`
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: min-content auto min-content;
  gap: 1rem;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.palette.bone};
  min-height: 100vh;
`;
```

This centers the entire content in a 3-row layout which is exactly what I want.

However, based on the image below, the footer is facing some issues. I need the footer to be full width with the constraint that the link in the footer ends at the same right edge as content. I think the issue is related to the `justify-content` but I need that to center the content.

[image]

Here's the JSX for the layout

```
<AppContainer>
      <AppHeader />
      <ViewContainer
        as="main"
        isExpanded={ isExpanded }
      >
        <ErrorBoundary>
          <Suspense>
            <Sidebar />
            <Container>
              <View />
            </Container>
          </Suspense>
        </ErrorBoundary>
      </ViewContainer>
      <AppFooter />
    </AppContainer>
```

Comment: Can you show header and footer components?

Comment: I'm no expert, but I would make a `.footer` grid-box for row 3 with somthing like: `grid-column-start: 1;
   grid-column-end: 2;
   grid-row-start: 3;
   grid-row-end: 4;` and then set justify-content to the right for that box only.